# Netbeans php поддержка коротких тегов?

Tags: netbeans

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы netbeans нормально определял и подсвечивал php-код в коротких тегах:

```
<?
print('hhh');
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Свойства проекта -> Исходные файлы -> Поставить чек на "Разрешить краткие теги (<?)"